# html tags in products attributes on woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

At this moment I'm using WooCommerce,and  I'm trying to insert HTML code in an attribute of a product but to save this escaping HTML tags

is there a way to place HTML tags in an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. Your changes will be added when the page is rendered. Example:

```
$('#link').attr('my-attr', 'my-value');
```